# asyncio - AttributeError: '_WindowsSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute 'create_future'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to learn asynchronous calls using Python 3 (3.6.0a1 to be exact).

I have gone to a dozen different tutorial websites, plus aiohttp and asyncio docs and keep running into the same error. I've spent more than a couple hours googling the error, as well as more than a few attempts to find the error here.

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/11/09/an-intro-to-aiohttp/
https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-asynchronous-programming-in-python-with-asyncio-232e2afa44f6

Here is the code, just a sample that I've pulled from any dozen of places:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def do_stuff():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://api.github.com/events') as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(do_stuff())
loop.close()
```

Here is the error:

File "

```
<path>\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 531, in read
    self._waiter = self._loop.create_future()
AttributeError: '_WindowsSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute 'create_future'
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried dozens of tutorial examples and they always result in the same AttribteError.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: 3.6.4 is the latest release. You'd be better of using that rather than an alpha release of an older version.

Comment: Hmm let me try that. I thought I was on an LTS version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dim provided the solution: I was (unknowingly) using an alpha release of an older version of Python.

old: 3.6.0a1
new: 3.6.4

All is well in the world. Thank you for such a quick and simple solution. I'll keep that in mind next time!

Comment: If the issue is now resolved, feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) your answer, so that the question is marked as answered.